# Combine corpora in tm 0.7.3

Tags: r, version, text-mining, backwards-compatibility

Using the text mining package `tm` for R, the following works in version 0.6.2, R version 3.4.3:

```
library(tm)
a = "This is the first document."
b = "This is the second document."
c = "This is the third document."
d = "This is the fourth document."
docs1 = VectorSource(c(a,b))
docs2 = VectorSource(c(c,d))
corpus1 = Corpus(docs1)
corpus2 = Corpus(docs2)
corpus3 = c(corpus1,corpus2)
inspect(corpus3)
<<VCorpus>>
Metadata:  corpus specific: 0, document level (indexed): 0
Content:  documents: 4
```

However, the same code in `tm` version 0.7.3  (R version 3.4.2) gives an error:

```
Error in UseMethod("inspect", x) :
  no applicable method for 'inspect' applied to an object of class "list"
```

According to `vignette("tm",package="tm")`, the `c()` function is overloaded:

> Many standard operators and functions (`[, [<-, [[, [[<-, c(), lapply()`) are available for corpora with semantics similar to standard
>   R routines. E.g., `c()` concatenates two (or more) corpora. Applied to
>   several text documents it returns a corpus. The metadata is
>   automatically updated, if corpora are concatenated (i.e., merged).

However, for the new version this is apparently no longer the case. How can two corpora be combined in `tm` 0.7.3? An obvious solution is to combine the documents first and create the corpus afterwards, but I'm looking for a solution to combine two already existing corpora.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have much experience with the `tm` package so my answer may lack some nuance in understanding of `SimpleCorpus` vs `VCorpus` vs other `tm` object classes.

The inputs to your call to `c` are the class `SimpleCorpus`; it doesn't look like `tm` comes with a `c` method specifically for this class.  So method dispatch isn't calling the right `c` to combine the Corpora in the way you'd want.  However, there is a `c` method for the `VCorpus` class (`tm:::c.VCorpus`).

There are 2 different ways to get past the issue of coercing `corpus3` to a `list`, but they seem to result in different structures.  I present both below and leave it up to you if they are accomplishing your end goal.

#### 1) You can call `tm:::c.VCorpus` directly when defining `corpus3`:

```
> library(tm)
> 
> a = "This is the first document."
> b = "This is the second document."
> c = "This is the third document."
> d = "This is the fourth document."
> docs1 = VectorSource(c(a,b))
> docs2 = VectorSource(c(c,d))
> corpus1 = Corpus(docs1)
> corpus2 = Corpus(docs2)
> 
> corpus3 = tm:::c.VCorpus(corpus1,corpus2)
> 
> inspect(corpus3)
<<VCorpus>>
Metadata:  corpus specific: 2, document level (indexed): 0
Content:  documents: 4

[1] This is the first document.  This is the second document. This is the third document. 
[4] This is the fourth document.
```

#### 2) You can use `VCorpus` when defining `corpus1` & `corpus2`:

```
> library(tm)
> 
> a = "This is the first document."
> b = "This is the second document."
> c = "This is the third document."
> d = "This is the fourth document."
> docs1 = VectorSource(c(a,b))
> docs2 = VectorSource(c(c,d))
> corpus1 = VCorpus(docs1)
> corpus2 = VCorpus(docs2)
> 
> corpus3 = c(corpus1,corpus2)
> 
> inspect(corpus3)
<<VCorpus>>
Metadata:  corpus specific: 0, document level (indexed): 0
Content:  documents: 4

[[1]]
<<PlainTextDocument>>
Metadata:  7
Content:  chars: 27

[[2]]
<<PlainTextDocument>>
Metadata:  7
Content:  chars: 28

[[3]]
<<PlainTextDocument>>
Metadata:  7
Content:  chars: 27

[[4]]
<<PlainTextDocument>>
Metadata:  7
Content:  chars: 28
```